# NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' during Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, gemfile

Is there a specific update to the Gemfile that needs to be made in order to run rspec/capybara feature tests? My gemfile is using `ruby '2.5.3'` and `'rails', '~. 5.2.4'`. I have another test app that is rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.1 that is not running into this issue. I have tried changing around the versions of rspec and capybara with no such luck. I know there is an issue with rake versions before Rake 11 where certain methods were removed. Would this be the cause or another version issue in Gemfile:
**Gemfile**
`ruby '2.5.3'`
`gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4'`

```
group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
gem 'rspec-rails', '3.1.0'
end

group :test do<br>
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsepc-rails` 3.1.0 was released in September 2014 and is not compatible with Rake 11.0.1 or 12+ - Upgrade to the latest 3.x release of rspec-rails(3.9.1 as of now)